# iOS7: method drawMapRect is deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode, android-mapview

I am trying to draw circle on my map view, but as I've noticed - method (void)drawMapRect is deprecated. Is there something new or any alternative?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/MKOverlayRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013138-CH1-SW6):

> Use an MKOverlayRenderer object instead.

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
```